# Способы сохранения в TChart

Tags: delphi

Как можно сохранить данные с графика

1. что б сохранялся не только видимый кусок, а весь график;
2. так что б можно было потом подгрузить данные обратно в чарт для работы с графиком.

Умею делать только, что б сохранялось картинкой и то только видимый кусок. Если можно сразу с примерами.

Answer (score 1):

используйте процедуру 
procedure SaveChartToFile(AChart: TCustomChart; Const AFileName: String; IncludeData, TextFormat: Boolean);

создается файл с расширением *.tee

--- Обратите внимание на переменную IncludeData в зависимости от нее либо график будет сохранен с данными, либо будут сохранены только параметры серий в виде шаблона.

для загрузки применяется процедура
procedure LoadChartFromFile(Var AChart: TCustomChart; Const AFileName: String);

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сохранять данные графика в текстовый файл, например:

```
var
    sx, sy: TStringList;
    i: integer;
begin
    sx := TStringList.Create;
    sy := TStringList.Create;
    for i := 0 to chart.Series[0].XValues.Count - 1 do
        sx.Add(FloatToStr(chart.Series[0].XValues.Value[i]))
    for i := 0 to chart.Series[0].YValues.Count - 1 do
        sy.Add(FloatToStr(chart.Series[0].YValues.Value[i]))
    sx.SaveToFile('x.txt');
    sy.SaveToFile('y.txt');
    sx.Free;
    sy.Free;
    end;
end
```

Потом читать их оттуда обратно и создавать на их основе новый график.

```
var
    sx, sy: TStringList;
    i: integer;
begin
    sx := TStringList.Create;
    sy := TStringList.Create;
    sx.LoadFromFile('x.txt');
    sy.LoadFromFile('y.txt');
    for i := 0 to sx.Count - 1 do
        chart.Series[0].AddXY(StrToFloat(sx[i]), StrToFloat(sy[i]))
    sx.Free;
    sy.Free;
    end;
end
```

P.S. Код не тестировался.

Comment: Способ интересный, но не совсем, то что хотелось. Хотелось, что б это был 1 файл, который содержал бы в себе график весь сразу, тк на одном чарте больше 1 серии.
Сейчас читаю про файлы .dat, тк в аналогичной программе сохраняются подобные файлы с расширением .datw, и нигде нет полной инфы, что конкретно можно сохранят и как сохранять туда. Можно ли сохранять график в в файлы .dat и потом извлекать оттуда обратно в чарт,  и если да, то как?

Comment: Перечитал кучу форумов, нигде нет информации по .dat, понял, что это своего рода архив (так?), но так и не нашёл, как туда запихать график, неужели способ, приведенный выше, - это самое лучшее для моего случая?